# Check if Facebook/Instagram ads comers clicked on a specific button on my website

Tags: google-analytics, ads, google-tag-manager, event-tracking, facebook-pixel

I would like to track clicks of a specific button on my website of people who came from the Facebook/Instagram ads I created.

I implemented the Facebook `pixel` which triggers on pageview.

I also put `gtag('send', 'event','apply btn')` on the Apply button. This shows me reports on Google Analytics but it doesn't show if those people came from the ads I created.

Is there a view on google analytics where you can see the name of the campaign the user came from, or is there something specific I might be missing in the configuration of the campaign or the gtag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add parameters to URLs to identify the campaigns that refer traffic.

**utm_source**: Identify the advertiser, site, publication, etc. that is sending traffic to your property, for example: google, newsletter4, billboard.

**utm_medium**: The advertising or marketing medium, for example: cpc, banner, email newsletter.

**utm_campaign**: The individual campaign name, slogan, promo code, etc. for a product.

There are also **utm_content** and **utm_term**.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en